# parallel programming and datasets with datatables

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datatable, dataset

I have a taskfactory application that generates new tasks to complete processing using multiple classes. Everything seems to work fine with occasional IOEXception errors at times. The latest errors involve the use of datasets and datatables where in each process that runs, I access a database table to extract 100000 ids which I use in my process. In doing so I add a datatable to the dataset and use the datatable in a different portion of the process.

When creating a new task I assumed that it would generate its own datatable and dataset in memory as a new process involves a new instance of the classes involved and it should be threadsafe. However I get the error 
' Datatable already belongs in this dataset'

Now after researching I found that you cannot create multiple datatables in the same set. So is there anyway around this or should I consider a different data structure like perhaps using a list?

```
Public class tprocess
....
 ....
   public shared dsCountry as new dataset
   public shared dstable as new datatable

  public shared sub main()

      do_processing()
 end sub

  public shared do_processing()

      try 
        dscountry.tables.add(dsTable)
        ...' sql steps to get data with sqldatareader
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're sharing the same `DataSet` and creating new `DataTable` instances in that one DS. Is that the case?

It can be tricky. For example, this would use the same instance of a DataSet:

```
void Method() 
{
   DataSet ds = null;

   Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate {ds = new DataSet(); /*work with ds */});
   Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate {ds = new DataSet(); /*work with ds */});
}
```

Comment: yes I am sharing the dataSet but technically I thought that when creating a new instance of the class it creates a new dataset and new datatables within its own instance.